# change api in eclipse cause error on R file-android

Tags: android

I try to change the api from 4.2 to 2.2(api 8).
I worked with Eclipse. 2.2 is install but after I change I get that element of R file unrecognized . For example I get "home cannot be resolved or is not a field" error on  android.R.id.home.

What is the reason?

Comment: try to clean your project

Comment: Try to check there is any error in any of your layout files..

Comment: I try to clean. In layouts there is no error
When I change back to 4.2 the error fixed- so there is no realy error..

Answer (score 2):

Error clearly says

> home cannot be resolved or is not a field" error on android.R.id.home.

You have imported `android.R.java` which is different from `R.java`, so try to remove import and then clean your project and make sure that you have imported yourpackagename.R.java

Comment: @user2073729 delete your R.java file and the clean project once.. And then press `ctrl+shift+o`

Comment: you should clean project and wait until build completes

Comment: I did it..the gen folder is empty

Comment: Deleting the R.java file is not the solution. If cleaning the project did not solve it, then deleting the R.java file won't help either. @user2073729 **You have to build your project with API 11+**. Nothing else will help, if you want to use android.R.id.home!

Comment: @user2073729 Go and find problems in the problems window of eclipse and please find and let us know any other problems apart from that.. Because if there are error in the project eclipse won't generate R.java

Comment: I have not other problem. When I insert to properties->android there are now no api available : "not target available"

Comment: @user2073729 Have you tried what, Ahmed suggested..Setting the API level 11 as target

Comment: When I insert to properties->android there are now no api available : "not target available". There is other way to change back?

Comment: @user2073729 ok then Goto `Windows-->Preferences-->select Android-->And choose the SDK location` and then apply

Comment: the location is correct.. but I have there the message:This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or above.  Current version is 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525.  Please update ADT to the latest version -where is adt>

Comment: @user2073729 ok then... Try to update adt go to `eclipse..>Help-->install new software-->-->add location https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and then update your adt` this will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

`android.R.id.home` is a framework-intern Id, that is used for the ActionBars up button. API 2.2 does not support the ActionBar → the Id is not available.

You have to build it against HC or higher in order to use it.

[This](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/ids.xml#L72) is the Ids file from the framework for API 17. You can see the home Id online 72. 
[This](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-2.3.3_r1/core/res/res/values/ids.xml) on the other hand is the Ids file for API 10, and it does not have the Id home.

Comment: I finally didn't use ActionBar , so I want to choose lower api but it doesnt work..

Comment: Then delete the code with android.R.id.home. It will work then. Also on a side note: Why would you want to build it with a lower API? You should always target the newest API.

Comment: You don't need a lower build SDK to install it on lower APIs

Comment: If you aren't using the ActionBar, then you can set this in your manifest `android:minSdkVersion="10"`

Answer (score 0):

Clean or Rebuild your project in eclipse.. it will generate the R file once again 
this should solve your problem